# Uncaught SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON

Tags: reactjs, json, mern

```
import {createContext, useEffect, useReducer} from 'react';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) || null,
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};

export const AuthContext = createContext(INITIAL_STATE);

const AuthReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN_START':
      return {
        user: null,
        loading: true,
        error: null,
      };
    case 'LOGIN_SUCCESS':
      return {
        user: action.payload,
        loading: false,
        error: null,
      };
    case 'LOGIN_FAILURE':
      return {
        user: null,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    case 'LOGOUT':
      return {
        user: null,
        loading: false,
        error: null,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const AuthContextProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AuthReducer, INITIAL_STATE);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(state.user));
  }, [state.user]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user: state.user,
        loading: state.loading,
        error: state.error,
        dispatch,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I am learning react and the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON" appeared

this is the part of the code that involves JSON.I am implementing login functionality using context api.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ky8Y3.png) please help me out of this error.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the value of user key undefined in your localStorage.
Possibly by setting the value with a variable that has a value `undefined`.
Please check that!